# Spring Webflux Controller : Get original request object in reactive chain

Tags: java, spring, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I have a spring webflux project. I have a controller method like this

```
@PostMapping("url")
public Mono<MyResponse> getMyResponse(@RequestBody Mono<MyRequest> myRequestMono) {

    return urlService.getUrl(myRequestMono)
            .doOnNext(url -> {
                System.out.println("Generated URL: Successfully ");
            })
            .map(dto -> MyResponse.builder().url(dto).build())
            .doOnError(e -> System.out.println("Error " + e));
}
```

My service class looks like this

```
public Mono<String> getUrl(Mono<MyRequest> myRequestMono) {
    return myRequestMono.map(myRequest -> {
        callSomething();
        return "something";
    });
}
```

What I want to do is, when I log the line "Generated URL: Successfully", I would like to log a field in MyRequest object coming in through the request.
How can I access that in `.doOnNext`

I saw that I can set this value in a context and access it using `transformDeferredContextual`.

I tried it by implementing `WebFilter` and adding it there, but cannot really access it in the controller

```
urlService.getUrl(myRequestMono)
            .transformDeferredContextual((stringMono, contextView) ->
                    stringMono
                    .doOnNext(url -> {
                        contextView.get("key") // cannot get the object from this.
                        System.out.println("Generated URL: Successfully ");
                    })
                    .map(dto -> MyResponse.builder().url(dto).build())
                    .doOnError(e -> System.out.println("Error occurred " + e)));
```

is this the right approach? If not how do I tackle this issue. I need to access the original request that I received in the Http request in my `.doOnNext` method. I can set this in my response object in service class and access it, but that is a bit hacky.

Answer (score 1):

```
@RequestBody Mono<MyRequest> myRequestMono
```

Actually in your case there is no need to use `Mono` as `@RequestBody` in controller, you can replace it with your object explicitly, there will be no blocking. And for further processing just wrap it with `Mono.just()`

So you can use your literal object in operators in your chain without worrying about blocking

According to WebFlux [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.0.0.M5/spring-framework-reference/html/web-reactive.html#web-reactive-http-body):

*The request body can be one of the following way and it will be decoded automatically in both the annotation and the functional programming models:*

```
Account account
```

— *the account is deserialized without blocking before the controller is invoked.*

```
Mono<Account> account
```

— *the controller can use the Mono to declare logic to be executed after the account is deserialized.*

```
Flux<Account> accounts
```

— *input streaming scenario.*